# Navbar layers on top of logo

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a live mockup page but running into issues with the navbar showing on top of the logo image. I've researched for answers and tried them but are not working as expected. How can I fix it so the navigation isn't layered on top the logo? I'd also like to either adjust the nav to the top of page when in mobile size, logo becomes hidden or keep the logo visible on the navbar in mobile size. This will also require media query breakpoints to smooth the transition of desktop to mobile. I'm kind of new bootstrap. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[link to image mockup](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/mockup.jpg)
[link to live webpage mockup](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/index2.html)
[link to css override](http://www.contractorshotline.com/email_blasts/images/stelter/starter-template2.css)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the live webpage mockup link, you have

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom, 
.navbar-fixed-top {
 position: fixed; 
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1030;
}
```

the z-index is overlapping all of your elements.

add

```
position: relative; 
z-index: 99999;
```

to your `.row-img` class

Comment: It works, for the most part. After making the browser somewhat smaller, some menu items seem to hide behind the logo. How do I prevent that and when in mobile size adjust the menu to be at very top of page with small logo appearing left of the mobile menu button?